# rsyslog seems to produce a lot of UDP port 53 datagrams when listening for ddwrt syslog packets

Tags: debian, debian-wheezy, dd-wrt

I am trying to have dd-wrt (syslogd via BusyBox) send syslog events to a Raspberry Pi that is running rsyslog. When I start the rsyslog (on the Pi) service listening on 514 UDP, the daemon starts spamming my router with datagrams on port 53 containing what looks like DNS requests. If I turn off the syslogd running at dd-wrt, the port 53 spam appears to diminish greatly but is still around one every 5 or 6 seconds. With syslogd running, the number jumps to 20 or 30 per second.

My question is: How can I turn off or correct this spamming? Is it just part of syslog that I did not know?

This is the rsyslog.conf (pardon the formatting, I'm new to serverfault):

```
#  /etc/rsyslog.conf    Configuration file for rsyslog.
#
#                       For more information see
#                       /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html



$ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support

$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514

# provides TCP syslog reception
#$ModLoad imtcp
#$InputTCPServerRun 10514


###########################
#### GLOBAL DIRECTIVES ####
###########################

#
# Use traditional timestamp format.
# To enable high precision timestamps, comment out the following line.
#
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate RSYSLOG_TraditionalFileFormat

#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022

#
# Where to place spool and state files
#
$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

#
# Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
#
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
###############
#### RULES ####
###############

if $fromhost-ip startswith '192.168.1.1' then /var/log/ddwrt.log

& ~


auth,authpriv.*                 /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none          -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                         /var/log/cron.log
daemon.*                        -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                          -/var/log/kern.log
lpr.*                           -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                          -/var/log/mail.log
user.*                          -/var/log/user.log


mail.info                       -/var/log/mail.info
mail.warn                       -/var/log/mail.warn
mail.err                        /var/log/mail.err


news.crit                       /var/log/news/news.crit
news.err                        /var/log/news/news.err
news.notice                     -/var/log/news/news.notice


*.=debug;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    news.none;mail.none     -/var/log/debug
*.=info;*.=notice;*.=warn;\
    auth,authpriv.none;\
    cron,daemon.none;\
    mail,news.none          -/var/log/messages


*.emerg                         :omusrmsg:*



daemon.*;mail.*;\
    news.err;\
    *.=debug;*.=info;\
    *.=notice;*.=warn       |/dev/xconsole
```

Comment: `My question is: How can I turn off or correct this spamming? Is it just part of syslog that I did not know?`  1)  Add the flags to the start up options that disable the DNS resolution.  `man rsyslogd`  2)  Yes (if you change syslog to rsyslog in your question).

Comment: My guess is you are trying to resolve the host names of the systems sending you log messages. you might want to try the `-x` option, or look in the config file to disable hostname resolution. http://linux.die.net/man/8/rsyslogd

Comment: This falls under a need to read the manual...

Thank you guys for the pointers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsyslog does reverse lookups of the ip adress of syslog hosts.

You could disable this behavior by using the rsyslogd command line option `-x`.

For Debian based systems add the option in the file `/etc/default/rsyslog` to the shell variable `RSYSLOGD_OPTIONS="-x"`.

Comment: option `-x` was the winner! I appreciate the direction.